# What is the best way to sort the NSSet that is coming as an attribute for another NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an `account` model and a `client` model. `account` has many `clients`. When I fetch an `account` object, I want all of the `client` objects to be sorted by name in the given `NSSet`. **What is the best way to approach this?**

*What I've tried so far is two things:*

1. Sorting the list into a seperate list. This works, but doesn't seem optimal
2. Googling "how to sort fetched attributes". I've gotten some results, but nothing straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSSet` (and the underlying subclass of `NSSet` that is used in the `NSManagedObject` property backing), and 'sets' in general are unordered.

Sorting into an array is probably what you want.  This can be done using `NSArray`'s `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` and  `NSSet`'s `allObjects`.

Alternatively, it is possible to swizzle the `NSManagedObjectMutableSet` class's `addObject/unionSet`/etc: methods to a wrapper that maintains a sorted array, that you could access via a category method but that may have other implications - by far the simplest solution would be to sort into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"indexOrder" ascending:YES];
    collectionViewData = [[goalManager rootGoalsForUser] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil]];
```

In this case, rootGoalsForUser was created like this:

```
- (NSArray *) rootGoalsForUser
{
    NSSet *goal = [uManager goalWithParent:nil];    // retrieves root level goals
    NSArray *rootGoalArray = [goal allObjects];
    if ([rootGoalArray count] <= 0)
        return nil;
    else
        return rootGoalArray;
}
```

So, it is a set, we put it in an array with allObjects, and then it is sorted after the method returns with an NSSortDescriptor.